# the usage Java RealVector

Tags: class, package, java

I need help to understand how to use the abstract class org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector of java.lang.Object in my program.

I have three classe, that should be using it. A Point, a Simplex and a Triangle.

The Simplex-Class should use the methods of the RealVector class to calculate the perimeter of an object, like triangle.

```
import java.lang.Object.*;

package org.apache.commons.math3.linear;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector.Entry;
import org.junit.Assert;
public class Point
{
    private int dimension;
    private double[] values;
    private RealVector rv;

    public Point(int d, double... values) {
        try {
            this.dimension = d;
            this.values = values;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            System.out.println("Bad Arguments");
        }
    }
    public double get (int i) {
        return values[i];
    }
    public int dim() {
        return dimension;
    }
}
```

When I compile that I get an error:

> You have changed the package statement to a package which does not
>   exist in this project.

So the question is: how to use the RealVector class in my program?

Comment: same problem to this i already answer someone just now read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43954513/5558072

Comment: Because org.apache.commons is a third-party package and you are importing their classes, you don't need to include a package statement. Remove `package org.apache.commons.math3.linear;`

Comment: also make sure that the name of your package is correct

Comment: If I remove this line, then compiler says: pachage org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector.Entry does not exist

Comment: So i thought I need to include the package, but iit gives me that other error

Comment: Your package is not `package org.apache.commons.math3.linear;`. The Java Tutorial is what you need first. Read the section on packages.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on the first lines of your code:

```
import java.lang.Object.*;

package org.apache.commons.math3.linear;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector.Entry;
import org.junit.Assert;
```

It has many problems:

1. The package declaration must come **before** the imports
2. You shouldn't put your own class into the package `org.apache.commons.math3.linear`. Put it inside your own package, named after your company/organization. You're not writing for the apache foundation.
3. `import java.lang.Object.*;` makes no sense. Object is a class, not a package. So you can't import all the classes inside java.lang.Object. And you don't need to import any class from java.lang: they're imported implicitly.
4. `import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealVector.Entry;`: you're never using this Entry class in your class. You're using the RealVector class, so that's the class you should import (although you're not really using it: you just have a private fiel of that type, which is never initialized not read, and is thus useless).
5. `import org.junit.Assert;`: you're not using this Assert class in your code either, so it shouldn't be imported. That class, BTW, is used to implement unit tests. It should be imported in unit tests, but not in production classes.

Start by fixing all this, and then ask aother question if you still have a compilation error, mentioning the exact and complete error. Make sure the jar file of the math3 apache library is in the classpath of your project: it's not bundled with the JDK, so you need to add it to the project.